# How to find maximum capacity available in overlapping time periods SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We are working on a room booking system, where the same room can be booked by different people as long as the capacity is not exceeded.

We are trying to calculate the maximum number of seats available for the whole time period requested for a new booking.

This is probably best explained with a diagram. Assume this room holds 100:

```
<-------I want to book this - How many seats are available?------->

   <---Booking 1: 10 seats--->       <---Booking 2: 10 seats--->
                       <---Booking 3: 10 seats--->
                                     <---Booking 4: 10 seats--->
```

So the minimum of the maximum available at any one time during the requested period would be 70 (Bookings 2, 3 and 4 overlap taking 30 seats out of action at this time).

How can this be calculated using SQL? We want the query to return the number of seats currently available for the requested timeslot, in the above case, 70.

The tables available are RoomBooking (room, start, end, capacity_taken) and Room (id, capacity).

We use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is the granularity of the timeslot booking - 1 minute, 5 minutes, 1 hour ...?

Comment: Bookings can be made to the minute. Comparisons can ignore the end of one booking being exactly equal to the start of another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific @room and time period from @start_time to @end_time, try:

```
;with cte as 
(select id, capacity, @start_time time_point
 from room where id = @room
 union all
 select id, capacity, dateadd(mi, 1, time_point) time_point
 from cte where dateadd(mi, 1, time_point) < @end_time)
select min(capacity_left) max_available from
(select c.time_point, max(c.capacity) - sum(b.capacity_taken) capacity_left
 from cte c
 join RoomBooking b
   on c.id = b.room and
      c.time_point >= b.start and
      c.time_point < b.end
 group by c.time_point) sq
```

Note that the maximum capacity that will be available throughout the *whole* booking period is the *smallest* available capacity at any point within the period - so in the example this will be 70 seats.

Comment: Very nice - be careful though, you won't get any result if there is no `RoomBooking` for `Room`. Could be fixed with left outer join. And on `sum(b.capacity_taken)` you would need a `ISNULL` - check.

Comment: P.s.: You also might want to include `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: So essentially, this is equivalent to looping over each `time_point` and keeping track of the minimum availability!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way to uniquely identify each booking. I'd suggest adding an identity column to the RoomBooking table and solve the problem like in the code below:

```
create table Room
(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered,
    capacity int not null
)
go
create table RoomBooking
(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered,
    room int constraint FK_RoomBooking_Room foreign key references Room(id),
    start_time datetime,
    end_time datetime,
    capacity_taken int
)
go

insert Room(capacity)
    select 100 union all
    select 200

insert RoomBooking(room, start_time, end_time, capacity_taken)
    select 1, '2012-02-29 10:00', '2012-02-29 12:00', 10 union all
    select 1, '2012-02-29 11:00', '2012-02-29 15:00', 10 union all
    select 1, '2012-02-29 14:00', '2012-02-29 16:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 14:00', '2012-02-29 16:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 14:00', '2012-02-29 16:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 14:00', '2012-02-29 16:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 13:00', '2012-02-29 15:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 15:00', '2012-02-29 17:00', 10 union all
    select 2, '2012-02-29 17:00', '2012-02-29 19:00', 10 union all
    select 1, '2012-02-29 14:00', '2012-02-29 16:00', 10

go

declare @roomid int = 1
declare @check_period_start datetime = '2012-02-29 13:00'
declare @check_period_end datetime = '2012-02-29 15:00'

select
    r.id, r.capacity - maxtaken.max_capacity_taken as remaining_capacity
from
    Room r
    join
        (
            select
                id, MAX(sum_capacity_taken) max_capacity_taken
            from
                (
                    select
                        r.id, SUM(rb2.capacity_taken) + min(rb1.capacity_taken) sum_capacity_taken
                    from
                        Room r
                        join RoomBooking rb1 on rb1.room = r.id
                        left join RoomBooking rb2
                            on rb1.room = rb2.room
                               and rb1.id <> rb2.id
                               and 
                               (
                                   (rb2.start_time <= rb1.start_time and rb2.end_time >= rb1.start_time)
                                   or (rb2.start_time <= rb1.end_time and rb2.end_time >= rb1.end_time)
                               )
                        where
                            rb1.end_time >= @check_period_start
                            and rb1.start_time <= @check_period_end
                            and rb2.end_time >= @check_period_start
                            and rb2.start_time <= @check_period_end
                        group by
                            r.id, rb1.id
                ) sct
                group by id
        ) maxtaken on maxtaken.id = r.id
where
    r.id = @roomid
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We did have a room booking id, I just forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  I first create a list of hours that compromise the appointment using a recursive CT named "hours".  Then for each hour, the CTE "hour_capacity" sums the amount of seats booked.  The final query calculates the number of seats that is unused each hour.

```
; with  hours as
        (
        select  @startdt as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(hour, 1, dt)
        from    Hours
        where   dateadd(hour, 1, dt) < @enddt
        )
,       hour_capacity as
        (
        select  h.dt
        ,       r.capacity
        ,       sum(b.seats) as seats_used
        from    @room r
        cross join
                hours h
        join    @booking b
        on      b.roomid = r.id
                and h.dt between b.startdt and b.enddt
        where   r.id = @roomid
        group by
                h.dt
        ,       r.capacity
        )
select  capacity - max(seats_used)
from    hour_capacity
group by
        capacity
```

[Full example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62759)